# on run nodemon server.js cmd asked for "How do you want to open this file?"

Tags: node.js, angular, cmd, server, nodemon

**Facing problem on running nodemoon server.js** in cmd/PowerShell Windows. I don't know why system act like that

sceenshot::::
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal instead of 'powershell' try running it in 'bash'-this worked for me